# Center item in GridLayout

Tags: android, grid-layout, gravity

I'm using a Gridlayout which is made in xml with a couple headers in the first line. Now I want to add new rows with items dynamical to the grid.
My Problem is the items are not centered in the cell and doesn't match with the headers.

This is the Grid in the xml

```
<GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/newGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="5"
            android:rowCount="4">
            <!-- Grid Header -->
            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/cellNo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/desity" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/voltage" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/problemIcon" />

</GridLayout>
```

This is for example how I try to add a TextView in the second row in the second cell.

```
    ...
    TextView cellnum = new TextView(getContext());
    cellnum.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    cellnum.setText("9");
    ...
    gridLayout.addView(cellnum);
```

The text seems to be in the right cell but its not centered right under the headline

This is the xml verison which i tried frist and worked perfect but I need to build it dynamicaly

```
               <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="9" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `layout_gravity` instead of `gravity` of `textView` to make it appear in the centre.

You are setting `layout_gravity` in the `xml` that is why it works, but dynamically you are only setting `gravity`.

**`Xml`File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/newGrid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="5"
android:rowCount="4">
<!-- Grid Header -->
<Space
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="cell number" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="destiny" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="voltage" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

**`Activity` Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.newGrid);

    //Adding new textView at row 1 column 0
    TextView cellNum = new TextView(this);
    cellNum.setText("9");
    gridLayout.addView(cellNum);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(cellNum.getLayoutParams());
    params.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    cellNum.setLayoutParams(params);

    //Adding new textView at row 1 column 1
    TextView cellNum1 = new TextView(this);
    cellNum1.setText("10");
    gridLayout.addView(cellNum1);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(cellNum1.getLayoutParams());
    params1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    cellNum1.setLayoutParams(params1);

 }
}
```

Comment: LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT and  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT is missing an import. But GridLayout.LayoutParams(...) is not accepted

Comment: doesn't work, the textview and even the headers are disappearing

Comment: I have posted all my code, and it works on my side. Please check if you are copying something wrong